# Getting collation confict in IF statment and need help resolving it please

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

A SQL script I am writing is generating the error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I am not familiar with this error and don't know how to deal with it. I have been able to determine it is caused by the last IF check in the script as once I remove it the script runs fine. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this issue? Here is my current code:

```
DECLARE @Source varchar(25);

SET @Source = 'DOD';
/*
Source options are:
    DOD
    SPRAGUEENERGY
    SRAPROD
*/

IF (@Source = 'DOD')
BEGIN
    USE DOD;

END

IF(@Source = 'SPRAGUEENERGY')
BEGIN
    USE SPRAGUEENERGY;

END

IF (@Source = 'SRAPROD')
BEGIN
    USE SRAPROD;
END
```

Comment: Are you sure this error is coming from this isolated piece of code? This doesn't seem likely, can you share more of the code?

Comment: That is all the code I have written so far and as soon as I remove the last if statement it works fine. I can set the other if statements to look the same and they work fine.

Comment: Ok, so what is your server's collation, what is the collation of SRAPROD, and what is the collation of the database where you're calling this code from?

Comment: Have you tried using COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT on your IF (@Source = '...')?  You can put it on both sides of the compare "@Source COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = 'SRAPROD' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT". I don't see how this should be necessary, but you can try.

Comment: Sorry I have been sick for a few days and have not been able to update. I am not sure what the collation (or even how to check that) is for each DB. I will give your solution a try RLF and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is interesting. I created your 3 databases using different collations for each database.  I tried starting from different databases to see the results.  Naturally I do not know which collations you used on each database, but apparently the SQL Server is (in fact) aware of this.

- FIRST - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
- DOD - SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
- SPRAGUEENERGY - SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
- SRAPROD - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

Depending on the database I start with (I tried all 4) some give collation errors and some do not. So...  The answer is:

IF (@Source COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = 'DBNAME' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)

This raises no errors no matter which database I start with.

Comment: I just tested this out and adding the collate to the if statements has correct the problem. Thanks.